# Ratio and Solutions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A glass contains 100 ml water. A man sips 20 ml of water from it and then adds 10 ml alcohol to it and the solution is mixed.He keeps repeating this process until the glass is empty.What will be the amount of water just after the man has taken his 4th sip?

Comment: what is "sip" ?

Comment: Since he sips 20 ml of "water" each time, after the 4th sip, the glass will contain 20 ml of water.

Comment: I think you are meant to assume mixing immediately after the alcohol is added!

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}\hline
S.no.&Water&Alcohol&Water:Alcohol\\\hline
1&100&0&-\\
2&80&10&8:1\\
3&80-20\times\frac89=\frac{560}9&10-20\times\frac19+10=\frac{160}{9}&7:2\\
4&\frac{560}9-20\times\frac79=\frac{420}9&\frac{160}9-20\times\frac29+10=\frac{210}9&2:1\\
\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots\\\hline
\end{array}$$
Does that give you a hint?

Comment: after evry sip 10 ml alcohol will be added , so the water:alcohol ratio won't remain constant at 8:1.So , in your calculation you need to consider 10 ml alcohol addition after step 3

Comment: @AyanBiswas edited.

Comment: Alcohol volume in the 4 step of your calculation is incorrect.It should be subtracted from (160/9) not (70/9)

Comment: @AyanBiswas edited

Answer (score 0):

After first sip, $80$ ml water, $10$ ml alcohol

In second sip, water consumed $\dfrac{80}{80+10}\cdot20$ml $=\dfrac{160}9$ml and alcohol consumed $\dfrac19\cdot20$ml

So, water remains  $80-\dfrac{160}9$ml  $=80\left(1-\dfrac29\right)=80\cdot\dfrac79$ ml and alcohol remains $10-\dfrac19\cdot20$ml $=10\cdot\dfrac79$ ml

After $10$ ml alcohol,  alcohol quantity will be $10+10\cdot\dfrac79$ml $=10\cdot\dfrac{16}9$ ml

and so on

Comment: Agreed.But is there a simpler way to do it? By this way the calculation is bit too tedious